# How to set up AWS connection

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, http, connection, ubuntu-18.04

For the first time, I have applied for an Amazon Web Service, choosing the Lightsail package specifically. After installing several modules through Putty, uploading the files through FileZilla, and launching the server with 'node app.js', I tried to ping the server IP from my local computer but failed.

I need to be able to connect to the IP in the browser so that my SSL verification can pass.

What should I do to establish the HTTP connection? What steps have I missed?

Comment: Is there a firewall in between on port 80 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a Lightsail instance, some network ports are opened by default. When a port is open, your instance can accept public network connections. You can change the network port settings for your Lightsail instance on the Networking tab of your instance management page.

You need to check the instance's firewall rules and make sure that HTTP is opened.

Looking at [this official documentation](https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en/articles/understanding-firewall-and-port-mappings-in-amazon-lightsail), it shows that port 80 is opened by default per your chosen operating system.

Comment: I have been able to connect to AWS with Putty. What I need is the HTTP connection.

Comment: Please check my edited answer

Comment: but where is the Networking tab??

Comment: strange... the rule for HTTP has already been added but still the pinging failed...

Comment: Ping is a part of ICMP and it's possible that ICMP requests are blocked. Try instead to test it using telnet, like so: `telnet instance_public_ip 80` . If you get a connection string then it means that port 80 is listening. Also, make sure that the service is actually running in the machine and listening on port 80, run: `netstat -plunt | grep 80` to do that.

Comment: ok. After enabling all TCP and UDP connections, pinging now works. Connection is still refused for telnet. I guess it has to do with my node.js server program...

Comment: Do you see that the node process opens the port in the output of netstat?

Comment: i don't think so. there is a line looking: 127.0.0.53:53  0.0.0.0:*

Comment: Seems to me that you need to change the node bind address to your instance’s public ip rather than 127.0.0.1

Comment: omg. i think i forgot to install Express.

Comment: still no use after sudo npm install -g express

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91248/discussion-between-itai-ganot-and-chong-lip-phang).